# "What kind of...?" Possible answers

Tags: questions

> What kind of car has she got?

As far as I understand, there are different ways to answer such a question: old-fashioned, red, comfortable, sporty, a BMW, etc.

Can this question be asked about her **old black** car? (=What does her car look like?)

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: As a language question, sure you can. Is there some hidden connotation you are asking about?

Comment: No special connotation, just a question about the apperance of her car.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask someone "**what kind of car do you have**" and they reply "**a black one**", it would be a kind of joke. It literally answers the question but it implies that the answerer has no interest in cars at all, and the only thing they know about *their own car* is its colour. It would be taken to be sarcasm, implying "**Don't talk to me about cars. I'm not interested**."

So you can answer "**an old black one**" but it might be taken to be slightly rude.

If you want to know what the car's colour is, just ask "**What colour is your car?**" or "**What does your car look like?**"

Comment: What does her car look like? - It looks like an old Porsche.

Comment: What does your car look like? - It looks like it's been in hell.

Comment: @SovereignSun Actually we would say "It looks like it's been *through* hell."

Comment: What kind of car has she got? - She's got an old black car. (And that's all I know about her car.) Is anything wrong with this question?

Comment: @Yulia There is nothing wrong with that question and answer. Both are nicely idiomatic.

Comment: If I wanted to know about the colour and age, I'd ask about the colour and age. If I ask "what kind..." I'm asking about the make, model or styling. Context is everything. I would say "What kind of car does she have?" "Well, I don't know exactly what type of car it is, but it's um black and er pretty old." "Right, so, how big?" "Oh its quite small, but its not like one of those tiny two seat cars. ...." The point being that conversation is rarely simple.

Comment: @SovereignSun Please don't edit answers just to bold phrases. Corrections of mistakes and obvious formatting errors (like using code formatting instead of block quote formatting) are good, but style issues should be left to the author of the post.

Comment: @ColleenV Alright, it's just much more simple to read it that way!

Comment: @SovereignSun I could debate that with you, but I think I would bore everyone :) I understand that you were being helpful and appreciate it. I will add a link talking about appropriate use of bolding on SE though: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262086/ I remember some advice I read about using bold and italics in my writing - "Use it for emphasis, but be careful that your e-mail doesn't end up looking like a [ransom note](https://cdn.someecards.com/someecards/filestorage/RmbmQBfacebook-ugly-photo-ransom-ecards-someecards.png).